# MySQL query to pair data

Tags: mysql, yii2

I'm working with MySQL and Yii2 (this part doesn't really matter as first I need a SQL query), to capture vehicles entering and exiting a location.
The data is stored in the DB as follows (data simplified here - it would typically be multiple vehicles in before a vehicle exited):

[image]

I need a query to extract "pairs" of data - so the entry and exit record pair. The "inout" column is 1 for entry and 2 for exit.
So ideally I'd need one line which will have both the entry and exit data for a particular visit.

Obviously a vehicle can't enter twice before it has exited, so I'm guessing the created_date may be a factor here.

Any guidance would be great, but this, right now, is beyond my basic SQL knowledge!

Thanks.

Comment: this can be done, but I would have gone with an `in` and an `out` column, and in and an out datetime too. Outs are not null, ins are null (or vice-versa). Outs happen first and are known, the in part is pending

Comment: What output are you looking for?  The last time it entered/exited?  Number of enters/exits?

Comment: Looking for the time the vehicle entered and exited. There may be times when the vehicle hasn't exited yet, so the exit time would be null. There may also be the case of the vehicle exits before it enters, so would need to figure that out. Otherwise the answer from seahawk below is about right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select entry_tab.driver_id, entry_tab.vehicle_id, entry_tab.created_date as entry_date_time,

(select min(exit_tab.created_date) from data_table exit_tab where exit_tab.driver_id=entry.driver_id and exit_tab.vehicle_id=entry.vehicle_id and exit_tab.inout=2 and exit_tab.created_date>entry_tab.created_date) as exit_date_time

from data_table entry_tab where entry_tab.inout=1
```

Assumption : A vehicle makes first entry and then exit.

Note: code is not tested. There may be small syntactic error.